# dynamically add rCharts to web page using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I would like to generate multiple `rCharts` Pie Charts based on a selection of `Group`, this `Group` can change depending on the data frame. I would like to use similar example as in here

https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/

```
someDF = structure(list(Variable.Type = c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", 
"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"), Total = c(2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 4), Market = c("Pete", 
"Pete", "Pete", "Sams", "Sams", "Sams")), .Names = c("Variable.Type", 
"Total", "Market"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

list = unique(someDF$Market)
```

In server.R

```
 output$somePieCharts = renderUI({
 list = unique(someDF$Group)
 plot_output_list = lapply(1:length(list), function(i){
   plotData = filter(someDF, Group==list[i])
   chartOutput(hPlot(Total~Variable.Type, data=plotData, type='pie'))
 }
                           )
 do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
})
```

In ui.R

```
uiOutput('somePieCharts')
```

Comment: Provide some data to make things more concrete.

Comment: Will you delete the question when we give you the answer again ? ;)

Comment: @JulienNavarre, why I would delete the question?

Comment: @Ramnath, please look at the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can modify the dynamic plots example for use with `hPlot`. I have just replaced `plotOutput` with `chartOutput` and `renderPlot` with `renderChart2`. The rest of the changes are self-explanatory.

```
library(shiny); library(rCharts)
Markets = unique(someDF$Market)
server = function(input, output) {

  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      chartOutput(plotname, "highcharts")
    })

    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })

  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
  for (i in 1:length(Markets)) {
    # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
    # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
    # of when the expression is evaluated.
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

      output[[plotname]] <- renderChart2({
        print(my_i)
        plotData = subset(someDF, Market == Markets[my_i])
        print(plotData)
        hPlot(Total ~ Variable.Type, data = plotData, type='pie')
      })
    })
  }
}

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),

  sidebarPanel(),

  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots")
  )
)

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```